# Restrict actions for some users with Sonata with a custom strategy

Tags: symfony, sonata

I would like to remove some actions like "DELETE" with forms when the current user is not the owner of the current object but does have an ADMIN role for editing it.

I would like to apply this behavior for lists (checkboxes) or when editing objects.

I currently use a voter that I use in Admin class like:

```php
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper){
        if($this->isCurrentRoute('edit') && !$this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('edit', $this->getSubject()))
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
...
}
```

Where I check with my own logic. But I don't know how I can use my voter for removing the delete action.

I first tried to remove actions on configureRoutes with my own logic but I didn't success. Also, I read that it was a bad choice due to the cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeeded but I am not sure it is the best solution.

I use my [voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) that manages my own logic. In my admin entity, I override the template for "edit".

```
class ProjectAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
...
public function getTemplate($name)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'edit':
                return 'Sonata/ProjectAdmin/edit.html.twig';
                break;
            default:
                return parent::getTemplate($name);
                break;
        }
    }
...
}
```

I created my template in `templates/Sonata/ProjectAdmin/edit.html.twig`

that contains:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% use 'SonataExtends/base_edit_form.html.twig' with form as parentForm %}

{% block form %}
    {{ block('parentForm') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Then I copied/pasted `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Ressources/views/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig` into `templates/SonataExtends/base_edit_form.html.twig`

I replaced the block:

```
 {% if admin.hasRoute('delete') and admin.hasAccess('delete', object) %}
    {{ 'delete_or'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delete', object) }}">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'link_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

for calling my voter:

```
 {% if admin.hasRoute('delete') and is_granted('delete', object) %}
     {{ 'delete_or'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
     <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delete', object) }}">
     <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'link_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

The only difference is `is_granted('delete', object)` instead of `admin.hasAccess('delete', object)`

As I said, it might not be the best way to proceed, so thank you for correcting me. But I didn't manage to override the logic of admin.hasAccess('delete', object).
For other admin classes, I only need to use my `getTemplate` function for using this logic.

PS:
I also added this code in my admin class for managing the delete action:

```
 public function preRemove($project){
        if (false === $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('delete', $project)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
        }
    }
```